# Creating a stack and iterator that runs thorugh the stack using a for loop

Tags: python, oop, iterator, stack

I'm trying to create a stack with the LIFO principal. I am able to do this using just the push and pop function. But I want to create a **iter** and a **next** function to traverse through the stack. Below is what I have tried, but can't really figure out the logic.

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
     self.stack = []
     self.START = None
     self.END = None

def push(self, item):
    self.stack.append(item)
    #print("item added to stack")

def pop(self):
    return self.stack.pop()
    #print("value removed according to LIFO")

def emptystack(self):
    return len(self.stack) == 0

def __iter__(self):
    self.Iterator = self.START
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.Iterator != None:
        stack = self.Iterator
        self.Iterator = self.Iterator.NEXT
        return node
    else:
        raise StopIteration


def fullstack(self):
    return self.stack

s = Stack()
s.push('1')
s.push('2')
s.push('6')
s.push('8')
s.push('11')
s.push('12')
s.pop()
s.push('50')
if s.emptystack():
   print("Stack is empty")
else:
   print(s.fullstack())
```

Comment: `self.Iterator` is initialized to `None` and is never changed, so the `if` statement in `__next__()` will always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Iterator` attribute will always be `None`, because you stop the iteration as soon as the first call to **next** happens. Think of **next** as being called for every item until there's no more items to process, from the Python documentation about `__next__`:

> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception

One thing you could do is initialize the `self.Iterator` to the stack's length (in `__iter__`), then on every step, decrement it until you reach 0 (and then raise StopIteration):

```py
def __iter__(self):
    self.Iterator = len(self.stack) - 1  # initialize to the index of the last element
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.Iterator >= 0:
        current_value = self.stack[self.Iterator]
        self.Iterator = self.Iterator - 1  # update for the next step
        return current_value
    else: # stop if self.Iterator is -1
        raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are `list` to store the stack elements, you can use the `iter` function of python to return the iterator and use it.

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
    #print("item added to stack")

    def pop(self):
        return self.stack.pop()
    #print("value removed according to LIFO")

    def emptystack(self):
        return len(self.stack) == 0

    def stack_iter(self):
        return iter(self.stack)

    def stack_iter_next(self, iterator):
        return next(self.Iterator)

    def fullstack(self):
        return self.stack

s = Stack()
s.push('1')
s.push('2')
s.push('6')
s.push('8')
s.push('11')
s.push('12')
s.pop()
s.push('50')

s_iter = s.stack_iter()

for x in s_iter:
    print (x)
```